# how to find remote server directory exist or not through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ant

I am using javascript inside my Ant script to pass the runtime network remote folder value as input. after passing that value i am finding that input folder path exists or not. but i am unable to do this.
my code is as below.

```
    <script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        importPackage(javax.io);
        importPackage(javax.swing);
        importPackage(java.lang);
        var deployment_machine = project.getProperty("var2");
        var deployment_machine = deployment_machine.substring(2,deployment_machine.indexOf("$")-2);
        var optionPane = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( 'Deployment location for GatewayFW in ' + deployment_machine + '?', null );
        var path = require('optionPane');
        if (path.existsSync("/the/path")) {
                // ...
            }

        if(!fso.FolderExists(optionPane))
        {
        var optionPane = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( 'Deployment location for GatewayFW in ?', deployment_machine );
        }
        else
        {
        project.setProperty('deploy_loc',optionPane);
        }           
    ]]>
    </script>
</then>
<else>
    <echo message="File need to check:- ${patch.path}/${patch.name}/GatewayFW_patch.zip is not exist"/>
</else>
```

`

can anyone help me out pls?

Answer (score 1):

`<script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            importPackage(java.io);
            importPackage(javax.swing);
            importPackage(java.lang);
            var deployment_machine = project.getProperty("var2");
            var deployment_machine = deployment_machine.substring(2,deployment_machine.indexOf("$")-2);

            do
            {
            var optionPane = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( 'Deployment location for GatewayFW in ' + deployment_machine + '?', null );

            var dir = new File(optionPane);
            }
            while(!dir.exists());
            project.setProperty('deploy_loc',optionPane);
        ]]>
        </script>`
here we have to assign the File("folder path") to one javascript variable like above var=dir =new File("folder path");
then we can perform the any operation over path.